# Deviseのサインアップをトップ画面に持ってきたい場合

Tags: ruby-on-rails

方法は２つあるなーと思い、２つ試してみました。

ひとつは、Deviseのコントローラーを作成し、サインアップ(`devise/registrations/new`)をrootで指定する方法です。
これは実装できたのですが、リダイレクトの指定などrouteやコントローラーに書くことが多かったので、もっと簡単な方法ないかなと思いました。

そこで、サインアップ画面を部分テンプレートにし、トップ画面のViewで`<%= render 'devise/registrations/new' %>`と書けば、コントローラーやrouteに書くことも少なくなるのではと思ったのですが、
`undefined local variable or method 'resource' for`とサインアップの`<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`にエラーが出ました。
このやり方は推奨されていないということでしょうか？

前者でやる方が無難なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

すでにログイン済みの人に対してはサインアップページを表示しても意味が無いと思うので、

- 未ログインであればどのページにアクセスしてもサインアップページにリダイレクト
- ログイン済みであれば要求されたページをそのまま表示

というアプローチがいいかなと思います。

まずApplicationControllerを変更します。

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # 常にログインを要求する
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # ...
```

続いて `config/initializers/devise.rb` を変更します。

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    # 未ログインでアクセスしてきたときはサインアップページへリダイレクト
    new_user_registration_path
  end
end

Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...

  # 上で定義したCustomFailureクラスを設定
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end

  # ...
```

これで上記の挙動が実現できるはずです。

参考: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Answer (score 0):

もう4年前の件ですので、今更感がありますが、devise使った時に、同じような事で「？？？」となったので
helperつかって対応が可能かと。以下のやり方でうまくいくかと思います。
https://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/